# jquery UI: tooltip code only

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using this [jQueryUI tooltip.](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

The [jQueryUI file](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js) is quite large as it contains all the other elements.

Do I need all that code to let the tooltip behave properly or could I remove some of the code?

Comment: jQuery UI has a builder [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/) right on it's download page. Just pick the pieces you need and deselect the rest. You'll get a slim down version without all the fat you're not using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't.

Here's your jQuery UI build with only tooltip selected: http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.3&components=1101000000000000000100000000000000

Feel free to customize this selection if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this possibility.